# How to format a multiplication table that is created with JOptionPane with HTML?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to integrate HTML in `JOptionPane`  and I could not get to format the table.

The CODE is:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class tabell1 {
        public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int p;
        String t="";
        String l="\n";
        for (int r=1; r <=10; r++) {
        for (int k=1; k  <=10; k++) {
            p=r*k;
            System.out.print(p+"");
            t=t+p+"";
        }
        t=t+l;
        System.out.println("");
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);
        }
    }
```

Anyone who could help me to format a multiplication table that is created with `JOptionPane` with HTML?

Comment: Separate the generation of the data from the presentation.  Don't worry about Swing; get the logic for the multiplication table right first.

Comment: what does this have to do with html or joptionpane?

Comment: I try to make the the frame of the tabel looka better.

Comment: setTitle("Multiplikationstabell");
 JLabel l = new JLabel(
    "<html><body><table border='2'>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "<td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>"+
    "<tr>"+
    "</table></body></html>", JLabel.CENTER);
  
   
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 1):

To show correctly as HTML in a Swing component, the data must be **formatted as HTML!**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class tabell1 {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int p;
        String t = "<html><body><table>";
        for (int r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
            t = t + "<tr>";
            for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++) {
                t = t + "<td>";
                p = r * k;
                System.out.print(p + " ");
                t = t + p + "";
                t = t + "</td>";
            }
            t = t + "</tr>";
            //t = t + l;
            System.out.println("");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)